# PPTX XML vector image support for non-EMF files?

Tags: pdf, powerpoint, openxml, vector-graphics

I understand that I can create a PPTX (Powerpoint) archive using an EMF file that is referenced in slideX.rels.xml. Can I do the same thing with any vector image format other than EMF (PDF, SVG, etc)? Can't seem to find this answered in OOXML specs anywhere...

Comment: No. You can only reference graphics file formats that PPT natively supports.  EMF, WMF, GIF, JPG, PNG.  OLE objects are a possibility ... for example, insert a PDF as an Object then have a look at the media folder inside the XML

Comment: thanks. tried to insert PDF as object but it did not let me do so-- only seems to allow office objects. Perhaps it could work if I were to install some other app, but I need to create PPTX files that will have no other dependencies so even if that's a possibility, it won't work for this purpose.

Comment: To insert any file as an object, there has to be an installed app that's an OLE server for the file type.  But as you say, that implies a dependency on another app, so won't do in your case.